# libvirt pfSense guest not able to obtain WAN-ip (DHCPv4) on bridged NIC

Tags: network-bridge

I'm trying to achieve having an Ubuntu host machine, with only one NIC, with multiple guests (VM's) and all of them (the guests) connected to the pfSense-guest.

What I think I need is 1 virtual NIC, and then create 2 bridges, so that the pfSense-guest can have one for WAN and the other for LAN. The other guests would then have the second bridge (LAN) connected to them so they can get their own IP-address with DHCP from the pfSense-guest.

The problem is, I don't seem to get and external IP address on the pfSense-guest. I've set-up pfSense to obtain it's WAN-IP with DHCPv4. My ISP allows me to have multiple IPv4-addresses, so that's not the problem. I've tested with other Ubuntu-guests and they are able to obtain a external IPv4-address from the same bridged-interface. Is this a problem with pfSense (compatibility-issue with bridged network?) or am I doing something wrong?

My configuration so far:

```
auto eth0
auto eth0:0
auto br0
auto br1

iface eth0 inet manual
iface eth0:0 inet manual

iface br0 inet dhcp # Modem (for external IPv4-addresses)
    bidge_ports eth0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0

iface br1 inet static # LAN (for pfSense to give out local IPv4-addresses)
    address 0.0.0.0 # We don't want and IP-address on this bridge for the host, pfSense will send out IP-addresses to guests over this bridge.
    bidge_ports eth0:0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Why is pfSense not able to obtain an external IP-address on the br0? Other guests are able to obtain an external IP-address without any problems.

Comment: I still have no clue why pfSense is not able to obtain an external IPv4-address through my bridge when other guests are able to without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

A simple reboot of the modem was not good enough. It seems to take approximately 10 seconds for my ISP to recognise the modem as down. The assigned external (public) IPv4-addresses are then removed so I can receive new ones. My ISP does not allow me to retrieve more then 4 external IP-addresses it appears.